# Traversable => Java Iterator

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

I have a Traversable, and I want to make it into a Java Iterator. My problem is that I want everything to be lazily done. If I do .toIterator on the traversable, it eagerly produces the result, copies it into a List, and returns an iterator over the List.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here...

Here is a small test case that shows what I mean:

```
class Test extends Traversable[String] {
      def foreach[U](f : (String) => U) {
         f("1")
         f("2")
         f("3")
         throw new RuntimeException("Not lazy!")
     }
}

val a = new Test
val iter = a.toIterator
```

Comment: According to the source code, `toIterator` is implemented by default as: `.toStream.iterator` which is lazy.

Comment: @paradigmatic Thanks for looking into it. I did the same, and reached the same conclusion, until I tested it. I've added a small test case that shows my problem.

Comment: @paradigmatic: yes, but toStream is implemented as toBuffer.toStream

Answer (score 5):

The reason you can't get lazily get an iterator from a traversable is that you intrinsically can't.  Traversable defines `foreach`, and `foreach` runs through everything without stopping.  No laziness there.

So you have two options, both terrible, for making it lazy.

First, you can iterate through the whole thing each time.  (I'm going to use the Scala Iterator, but the Java Iterator is basically the same.)

```
class Terrible[A](t: Traversable[A]) extends Iterator[A] {
  private var i = 0
  def hasNext = i < t.size   // This could be O(n)!
  def next: A = {
    val a = t.slice(i,i+1).head  // Also could be O(n)!
    i += 1
    a
  }
}
```

If you happen to have efficient indexed slicing, this will be okay.  If not, each "next" will take time linear in the length of the iterator, for `O(n^2)` time just to traverse it.  But this is also not *necessarily* lazy; if you insist that it must be you have to enforce `O(n^2)` in all cases and do

```
class Terrible[A](t: Traversable[A]) extends Iterator[A] {
  private var i = 0
  def hasNext: Boolean = {
    var j = 0
    t.foreach { a =>
      j += 1
      if (j>i) return true
    }
    false
  }
  def next: A = { 
    var j = 0
    t.foreach{ a => 
      j += 1
      if (j>i) { i += 1; return a }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Terribly empty")
  }
}
```

This is clearly a terrible idea for general code.

The other way to go is to use a thread and block the traversal of foreach as it's going.  That's right, you have to do inter-thread communication on every single element access!  Let's see how that works--I'm going to use Java threads here since Scala is in the middle of a switch to Akka-style actors (though any of the old actors or the Akka actors or the Scalaz actors or the Lift actors or (etc.) will work)

```
class Horrible[A](t: Traversable[A]) extends Iterator[A] {
  private val item = new java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue[Option[A]]()
  private class Loader extends Thread {
    override def run() { t.foreach{ a => item.put(Some(a)) }; item.put(None) }
  }
  private val loader = new Loader
  loader.start
  private var got: Option[A] = null
  def hasNext: Boolean = {
    if (got==null) { got = item.poll; hasNext }
    else got.isDefined
  }
  def next = {
    if (got==null) got = item.poll
    val ans = got.get
    got = null
    ans
  }
}
```

This avoids the `O(n^2)` disaster, but ties up a thread and has desperately slow element-by-element access.  I get about two million accesses per second on my machine, as compared to >100M for a typical traversable.  This is clearly a horrible idea for general code.

So there you have it.  Traversable is not lazy in general, and there is no good way to make it lazy without compromising performance tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

I've [run into this problem before](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3958#comment-51475) and as far as I can tell, no one's particularly interested in making it easier to get an `Iterator` when all you've defined is `foreach`.

But as you've noted, `toStream` is the problem, so you could just override that:

```
class Test extends Traversable[String] {
  def foreach[U](f: (String) => U) {
    f("1")
    f("2")
    f("3")
    throw new RuntimeException("Not lazy!")
  }
  override def toStream: Stream[String] = {
    "1" #::
    "2" #::
    "3" #::
    Stream[String](throw new RuntimeException("Not lazy!"))
  }
}
```

Another alternative would be to define an `Iterable` instead of a `Traversable`, and then you'd get the `iterator` method directly. Could you explain a bit more what your `Traversable` is doing in your real use case?

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for actual laziness.  See my answer.

Comment: It does work in the sense that it passes the test. I agree that there are other problems though.